# Why are both save and update queries triggered?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-boot with spring-data-jpa and hibernate on MySQL database.

I have defined an entity like so-

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@IdClass(TestTableId.class)
@Builder
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable implements Serializable, Persistable<TestTableId> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 150967283000000000L;

    @Id
    private String idCol1;

    @Id
    private String idCol2;

    @Id
    private String idCol3;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "insert_time", columnDefinition = "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date insertTime;

    // other columns

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public TestTableId getId() {
        return new TestTableId(idCol1, idCol2, idCol3);
    }
}
```

My `IdClass` is defined as follows-

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestTableId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6903451981600000000L;
    private String idCol1;
    private String idCol2;
    private String idCol3;
}
```

I'm trying to `INSERT` a list of `TestTable` instances and I'm also supplying values to all `idCol1`, `idCol2` and `idCol3` since these id columns are all generated in app.

Following is the method I'm using for saving entities-

```
@Transactional
public List<TestTable> saveTestTable(List<TestTable> records) {
    return testTableRepository.saveAll(records);
}
```

When this runs, it fires both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries on DB. How can I avoid that as only `INSERT` query would do the job?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're encountering, where Hibernate issues both INSERT and UPDATE statements for a newly created entity, is likely due to the way you've implemented the isNew() method in your entity class. Specifically, your TestTable class always returns true for the isNew() method. This method is intended to inform Spring Data JPA whether the entity should be considered new (and thus subject to insertion) or existing (and thus subject to updating). Always returning true causes Spring Data JPA to treat every save operation as if it's dealing with a new entity, even after it's already been persisted.

In your case, since idCol1, idCol2, and idCol3 are application-generated identifiers, you need a reliable way to determine if an entity instance is truly new or if it represents a pre-existing record in the database. One common approach is to check if the identifier fields are null or have some default unset value that you use to indicate a new, unsaved entity. However, since your identifiers are generated in the application and presumably always set before saving, you'll need a different strategy.